# Facebook graph API, how to "like" post-id with Application Access Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to like a specific post on behalf of a facebook-user with a **desktop application**, through the graph api. Application is designed to use [architechture variant 3rd from the top](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#architecture)

The application has an [application access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens). The test-users have granted the app all possible permissions, but only publish_actions, publish_stream should be needed(*1).

The solution (*2) for a web-based application which has access to a user access token is simple:
then you simply:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/<post-id>/likes?access_token=ABC123...
```

Posting to a user-ids feed and commenting is no problem. But what is the syntactically correct way of liking facebook graph objects with post-ids?

I've tried og.likes:

But the interface seem to only allow me to like objects defined in my facebook application.
Ex:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/<user-id>/likes?object={"fb:post_id":"<post-id>","og:title":""}access_token=ABC123...
```

Which actually gives a returned action-id, but they never show up as a real "like" nor contribute to the like count of a comment/post.

If I give the object parameter og:title a value it shows up, but only as a "like action".
Which shows up in the timeline as:

```
 <test-user name> likes an object on <app-name>
```

Side note: When defining new objects for your app fb:post_id fb:comment_id, and a couple of other ones are reserved. And should return an id which is reachable with through the graph-api, so I figured it would be possible to create similar objects to what is created through.

(1) developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-extended-publish

(2) stackoverflow.com/questions/4534975/like-posts-over-facebook-graph-api